# Struggling with getting overflow right in CSS

Tags: css, css-position, overflow

For some reason I'm getting stuck on this fairly simple problem. I want a scrollable "website" (just a looong jpg screenshot) framed through an iPad as part of my portfolio. The goal is to show the experience of visiting the site in its entirety without taking up a huge amount of space on the page.

For some reason, I haven't been able to get the overflow working right. This doesn't seem like a hard problem on the surface, but it's got me stumped. Any nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

```css
    .nest {
     position: relative;
    height: 712px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .ipad {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0;
    bottom:auto;
    left:0;
    }
    .container{ 
    height: 940px;
    width: 712px;
    position: absolute;
    top:45px;
    background: red;
    }
    .content { 
     width: 712px;
     overflow: auto;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="nest">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="content" src="https://i.ibb.co/bWmxzkv/Screenshot-2021-05-05-AAA-Service-Company-Demolition-Contractors.png">
    </div>
    <img class="ipad" src="https://i.ibb.co/kcRh56j/ipad-frame-copy.png">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your `.ipad` is top of the `.content` and mouse scroll is doing its job on the `.ipad` image but you want to scroll the screentshot image!

```
    <style>
        .nest {
            position: relative;
            height: 712px;
        }

        .ipad {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .container {
            height: 875px;
            width: 660px;
            left: 26px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 73px;
        }

        .container > div {
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .content {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>


    <div class="nest">
        <img class="ipad" src="https://i.ibb.co/kcRh56j/ipad-frame-copy.png">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <img class="content"
                src="https://i.ibb.co/bWmxzkv/Screenshot-2021-05-05-AAA-Service-Company-Demolition-Contractors.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here I changed the order in HTML to fix the z-axis problem, you may also want to use `z-index: number` in your CSS to fix this too.

Comment: @mohammed-reza-hrosravian thank you, that absolutely did it! Simple explanation, quick and easy fix.

I've never seen someone use a ">" in CSS before, and Google isn't coming up with anything. Can you tell me what it's doing there (.container > div)?

Comment: @acollin18 you're welcome. Yes it's a css selector and you can find them in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) at this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and this specific selector ">" as w3schools said is used to select elements with a specific parent and you can find its detials in this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow-y: scroll;` from `.nest` class, and add it to `.container` class.

```css
.nest {
  position: relative;
  height: 712px;
}

.ipad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 940px;
  width: 712px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
  width: 712px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nest">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="content" src="https://i.ibb.co/bWmxzkv/Screenshot-2021-05-05-AAA-Service-Company-Demolition-Contractors.png">
  </div>
  <img class="ipad" src="https://i.ibb.co/kcRh56j/ipad-frame-copy.png">
</div>
```